# Javascript form validation needs fix

Tags: javascript, html, validation, dom

I'm trying to make a basic form validation but it's not working. I need to make it in such a way that after validation is passed, THEN ONLY it submits the form. I'm not sure how to do it though. My code is below.

[Important request]
** I'm actually pretty new to this so if possible I would like to get some concrete information/explanation concerning the DOM and how to manipulate it and style it (W3School is NOT helping) **

```
<form id="reg" method="POST" action="user.php" onsubmit="return validate()">

    <label for="first">First Name: </label>
    <input id="first" name="first" type="text" value="">

    <label for="last">Last Name: </label>
    <input id="last" name="last" type="text" value="">


    <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form> 



function validate(){

    if(document.getElementById('first').value == ""){
        alert('First Name Blank!');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

    if(document.getElementById('last').value == ""){
        alert('Last Name Blank!');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about how it refreshes when you submit it?

Comment: Or do you mean it submits no matter what?

Comment: It submits no matter what. I was expecting it to validate first, then submit if validation was good.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function validate() {
  var validForm = true;
  var msg = '';

  if (document.getElementById('first').value == "") {
    msg += 'First Name Blank! ';
    validForm = false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('last').value == "") {
    msg += 'Last Name Blank! ';
    validForm = false;
  }
  if (!validForm) {
    alert(msg);
  }

  return validForm;
}
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/xwyXiE?p=preview)

Comment: This is perfectly working. But I got one question, what is the purpose of the if(!validForm) and return validForm?

Comment: 1. `if (!validForm)` is just for show alert when form is no valid - even if two input are empty it show only one alert. 2. `return validForm;` is to avoid send the form to server if it is no valid. In html onsubmit="return false" - means don't send the form and onsubmit="return true" means send the form. You use in html onsubmit="return validate()" so your function validate() should return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation function only validates the first name. Whether it's valid or not, the function returns before checking the last name.

```
function validate(){

    if(document.getElementById('first').value == ""){
        alert('First Name Blank!');
        return false;        // WILL RETURN EITHER HERE ...
    }else{
        return true;         // ... OR HERE
    }
```

The `return` statement will exit the function at the point it appears, and other code after that is simply not executed at all.

Instead of doing it that way, keep a flag that determines whether the fields are all OK:

```
function validate(){
    var isValid = true; // Assume it is valid

    if(document.getElementById('first').value = ""){
        alert('First Name Blank!');
        isValid = false;
    }

    if(document.getElementById('last').value == ""){
        alert('Last Name Blank!');
        isValid = false;
    }

    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: It only has to validate one, if it is false then they expected it to tell them and let them fix it.

Comment: @Lugia101101 the first `if` statement will return either `true` or `false`, so the second if statement will not be evaluated **ever**.

Comment: @Pointy So all it does is check if the value is null and the makes isValid = false? Correct me if I'm wrong, if I include the return true, even if all the values are null, the last return true will eventually make all the return false for the previous null boxes invalid? Please clear this out :)

Comment: @SabTheCoder the `return` statement **immediately exits the function**.  It doesn't "build" a return value, it says, "return right now!"

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code to check for validation *and* stop it from submitting if it is incorrect data.

```
<form id="reg" method="POST" action="user.php">

    <label for="first">First Name: </label>
    <input id="first" name="first" type="text" value="">

    <label for="last">Last Name: </label>
    <input id="last" name="last" type="text" value="">


    <button type="button" id="submit">Register</button>
</form> 


document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function(){
    if(validate()){
         document.getElementById('reg').submit();
    }
}


function validate(){

    if(document.getElementById('first').value == ""){
        alert('First Name Blank!');
        return false;
    }else if(document.getElementById('last').value == ""){
        alert('Last Name Blank!');
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

All I have done here is made the submit button a regular button and handled submitting via JS, When an input of type `submit` is clicked the page will submit the form no matter what. To bypass this you can make it a regular button and make it manually submit the form if certain conditions are met.

Comment: And it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code can be:

```
document.getElementById('submit').onclick = function () {
    if (validate()) {
        document.getElementById('reg').submit();
    }
}

function validate() {
    if (document.getElementById('first').value == "") {
        alert('First Name Blank!');
        return false;
    } else if (document.getElementById('last').value == "") {
        alert('Last Name Blank!');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use  if(validate()){document.getElementById('reg').submit();}}

Comment: because if validate() is true then it means all the fields are filled so on button click your form can continue.